# Как оформить следующие предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

Нет спроса — нет предложения, так говорит рынок.

Согласно Розенталю, "Нет спроса - нет предложения" - так говорит рынок. Но не уверена.

Но, как говорил незабвенный премьер, хотели как лучше, а получилось как всегда.

dic. academic пишет, что если цитата находится внутри основного текста, она всегда отделяется от собственно авторской речи: пунктуационно (кавычками) или синтаксически (с помощью оборотов «как сказал», «как говорил», «по словам»).  Т.е. получается, что кавычек ставить не нужно. Но хочу убедиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Нет спроса - нет предложения" - так говорит рынок. - верно, потому что в авторских словах содержится характеристика прямой речи, запятая опускается перед "так".

Но, как говорил незабвенный премьер, хотели как лучше, а получилось как всегда. - нет кавычек, потому что оформлена чужая речь с помощью вводного предложения с указанием на источник.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Можно и без запятой: "Нет спроса - нет предложения" - так говорит рынок.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Упрощённый вариант оформления прямой речи  применяется при наличии указательных слов. В этом используются кавычки, но нет запятой перед словами автора:   «Нет худа без добра» – так решили мы, выслушав его рассказ. «Ничего не случилось» – так говорил ум. «Будет буря» – вот что подумали все. «Будь внимателен и осторожен» – вот что он мне сказал.

Также: «Украл, дескать, но не на церковь иду, Христу не враг» ― вот что говорит себе нынешний преступник сплошь да рядом (достоевский).

Или вообще без кавычек, если предложение простое, а авторство условно: Увы! нет этой руки! нет этой крепкой руки! - вот что говорит вам тысячекратно повторяемый опыт (Салтыков-Щедрин).